# Name of technique where a function takes a single argument, does some non-mutating work, and returns the same argument?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming

I find myself wrapping values in a function that does some work, and then simply returns the value again.  It seems like it should already have a name, can anyone help me?

```
shout = (val) ->
    console.log val + " put in safe!"
    return val

safe = []
safe.push "shoe"
safe.push shout("dubloon")
```

Given the *CoffeeScript* above, `shout` could be described as a <*half-pipe?*> function, and most developers would instantly understand without seeing the implementation.

**Edit**: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm leaning toward the analogy of a plumber's T-splitter pipe  (1 input, duplicated output).

Comment: Looks like a shell command [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) to me, and a [similar function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) in Python, though both work with sequences.

Comment: look a like [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Identity_monad)